# How to render several components with a ternary operator in JSX/React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Sorry if any of my terminology is wrong, I'm not sure what this things are called. I've seen some people deconstruct components in this way:

```
// instead of
return (
  <div>
    <Component />
  </div>
)

// they do this
const component = (
  <div>
    <Component />
  </div>
)

return (
  {component}
)
```

I like it because it keeps code more organized, I don't know exactly what this method is called which makes it a little hard to look for answers somewhere else. My question is how do I put several components inside a ternary operator in his way? something like this:

```
const component = (
  <div>
    <Component />
  </div>
)
const otherComponent = (
  <div>
    <OtherComponent />
  </div>
)

return (
  {this.state.conditional ? component otherComponent : ""}
)
```

If I try this the app fails to compile and the error is: Parsing Error: unexpected token, expected "}".

I've tried several variations like wrapping the variables in curly braces, commas, or something else but nothing seems to work. I'm sure I'm missing something key here.

Comment: I voted up the answer from Brian but, more generally, just know that you can only  ever render a single parent with conditional JSX. It just needed a container for those components to return as a single parent. The JSX fragment approach is fine and quick and dirty without much re-writing. You could, however, just create a container component for both of them and have it return a single div/fragment with the two components as children. That would probably be a touch cleaner in your ternary and, in my opinion, is especially helpful if you end up needing to style the container in the future.

Comment: Yes! I didn't want to create a parent element because it was going to take some time to style and just wanted a fast solution, but as you said, it would be better to do so. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just wrap them in a fragment like this and it should work:

```js
{this.state.conditional ? <>{component} {otherComponent}</> : ""}
```

You're having an issue because you're basically trying to return two things from the ternary. It'd be like a function doing `() => {return a; return b;}`. Even if it did work, you'd get an error for rendering more than one react element.

By wrapping it in a single tag like a fragment, you're telling it to return a single element that's composed of two values.

Comment: This is correct! thanks, such a small thing but very important.